# Finding the sum of an infinite series of simultaneous equations:

Tags: sequences-and-series, systems-of-equations

I am trying to understand a system of simultaneous equations that I found easiest to express as shown below:
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=(AB-1)x_n+By_n
\\
y_{n+1}&=ACx_n+Cy_n
\end{align}

I.e. $x$ and $y$ are variables in an infinite series, and $A$, $B$, and $C$ are constants. In this specific case, $x_0=1$ and $y_0=0$.

What I want to do is analytically find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n$.

I have a few different constants for some different contexts. One set gives a sum that converges and the other gives a sum that trends to infinity. I have solved them numerically for work purposes but the convergent sums I have arrived at are suspiciously whole for whole constants, which makes me think there is a clean analytical solution that I'm missing.

Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if $X=\sum_{n=0}^\infty x_n$ and $Y=\sum_{n=0}^\infty y_n$ both converge, then \begin{align}X-1&=(AB-1)X+BY\\Y&=ACX+CY\end{align} after summing (i.e., doing $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ on) the given recurrence relations.

Solving, we get $X=(1-C)/D$ and $Y=AC/D$, where $D=2(1-C)-AB$.

Comment: Ah yes this makes sense! Because the series converges, the sums of $x$ and $y$ approach the same respective values for $n$ and $n+1$ terms as $n$ approaches infinity. And then we can just solve the regular set of simultaneous equations. Thanks very much for your help in understanding this problem.